# how to get admin user access level in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, acl

Is there a way to know the `access level` of the current logged in user to see if the user is granted with "`all`" or "`customized`" access role?

i can get the user role data but i can't seem to understand/find the `access level` so that i can apply some logic to my code (`collection`).

`Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()->getData();`
above statement prints:

```
Array
(
    [role_id] => 34
    [parent_id] => 0
    [tree_level] => 1
    [sort_order] => 0
    [role_type] => G
    [user_id] => 0
    [role_name] => Demo
    [gws_is_all] => 1
    [gws_websites] => 
    [gws_store_groups] => 
)
```

how can i get the information here on `access level (all, customized)` of the assigned role to the user?

much appreciated.

ps: i posted the same question on stackoverflow but this seems to be the specific place for magento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get all access details by below code

```
$roleId= Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()->getData('role_id');
if(!empty($roleId)){
    print_r(Mage::getModel('admin/rules')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('role_id',$roleId)->getData());
}
```

Comment: thanks, using this got me an array where i can use the resource_id to see if it has "all" access. `$rule=Mage::getModel('admin/rules')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('role_id',$role['role_id'])
                ->getFirstItem()
                ->getData(); `

Comment: in array you got permission column if its allow then this user has all privilege to access

Comment: well glad to hear that @MadMax

Answer (score 1):

There’s no direct access resources via the Core model api. Instead, the Roles model contains a getResourcesTree method which will allow you to programmatically access a list of resources with code something like this

```
$resources = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getResourcesTree();
$nodes = $resources->xpath('//*[@aclpath]');            
echo '<dl>';
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    echo '<dt>' . (string)$node->title . '</dt>';
    echo '<dd>' . $node->getAttribute('aclpath') . '</dd>';
}
echo '</dl>';
```

The roles are modeled simple non EAV  model class

```
Mage_Admin_Model_Roles
Mage::getModel('admin/roles')
```

for getting user role against id  try the following

```
$username = 'admin';
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);
```